# Не отображается ActionBar

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, activity, gradle

После создания проекта в IntelliJ IDEA форма имеет такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в `style.xml` изменить строку:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

На:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

То контролы на форме появляются, но `ActionBar` нет!

Если поиграться с кнопкой `Theme in Editor`, то `ActionBar` появится, но он не будет иметь цвета которые указаны в `style.xml`

Также я пробовал менять `API Version in Editor` - безрезультатно, а ещё пробовал:

- В `build.gradle` добавлять/менять/удалять строку:

  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
- Перейти с `ActionBar` на `ToolBar`
- И ещё много чего пробовал

Что делать? Подскажите, мне, пожалуйста!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pony.test_1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/login_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:imeActionId="6"
                        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Разметку Layout покажите и весь style.xml

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, добавил

Comment: А чем Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar не подошла?

Comment: @yno7, Вы мой пост читали вообще? Тем что так Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar не отображаются контролы на форме, а так Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar отображаются. Просто пробую по разному, пытаюсь решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто в build.gradle изменил строку:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

На:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

И всё заработало!!!

P.S В `style.xml` стоит `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`